# Как на основании шаблона построить таблицу Excel и внести в нее данные?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

Всем привет! 
Есть такой вот шаблон таблицы Excel :

[image: Шаблон таблицы]

У меня есть 3 переменные `minValue`, `avgValue`, `maxValue`. Им присвоен тип `String` и в них уже есть определенные значения (получаю через API).

Их нужно вставить в Темп, в мин, макс, и сред.

Как это сделать? Копаюсь с EPPLus, но ничего что-то не получается.

Comment: Что именно не получается, в каком месте? Покажите код.

Comment: На Гитхабе у них куча примеров: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus